# Как правильно сверстать такой блок с карточками? (фото в описании)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильно сверстать блок с карточками, которые выходят за пределы сетки (как на изображении)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сам что сделал и что именно не получается? Советую выложить сюда код, в противном случае, боюсь вопрос закроют без ответа...
Почитай это 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и это  
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Отрицательный margin, либо сетку исправить.

Comment: Это ли не на full-width container элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать один из контейнеров на всю ширину экрана, нужно его поместить в другой враппер, а после блока вернуться к предыдущей конструкции:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%
}

.content {
  background: navy;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=content>
    обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=wrapper_2>
  <div class=content>
    на всю ширину<br>на всю ширину<br>на всю ширину<br>на всю ширину<br>на всю ширину<br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=content>
    обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>обычный враппер<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;  
}

.wrap-big {
  padding: 35px 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container wrap">1-й</div>

<div class="container-fluid wrap-big">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container wrap">3-й</div>
```